# restful web services HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: rest, maven, glassfish

After deploying the ejb project and the web project on glassfish and  when I run my webservice PatientService  I have HTTP Status 404 - Not Found. this is my code :

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Named
@Path("/patient")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class PatientService {

    @Inject
    private PatientEntityFacade patientEntityFacade;

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;


    @GET()
    @Path("/findALL")
    public List<PatientEntity> findAll(){
        return patientEntityFacade.findAll();
    }
}
```

And this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

can you help me please ?

Comment: What URL are you trying to call?

Comment: I tried : http://localhost:8080/monitopsy-api/patient/findALL , http://localhost:8080/monitopsy-api/api/patient/findALL , http://localhost:8080/monitopsy/api/patient/findALL , http://localhost:8080/monitopsy-ejb/api/patient/findALL ... nothing work !

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the project name? Like localhost:8080/api/patient/findALL? As far as I know web containers do not add the application (or module) name as a context-path. Also you defined that GET endpoint consumes an XML, which is slightly unusual for a get endpoint (tough you will receive 415 if you don't set Content-type header)

Comment: when i try http://localhost:8080/monitopsy-api/ i have as result monitopsy ok but when i try http://localhost:8080/monitopsy-api/authentication some times i have 505 error and some times i have 404 error :/

Comment: 505 error? Like invalid HTTP version? Also where does the authentication endpoint comes from, I thought you tried to call the findALL endpoint. If something is working on monitopsy-api, than that is your context path. Is there nothing in your logs?

Comment: sorry I mean a "500 error" realy so sorry. I should test localhost:8080/monitopsy-api/api/authentication first because it give me a token then i use this token to test localhost:8080/monitopsy-api/api/patient/findALL